# gnome-keyring-daemon components and their use

Tags: key-authentication, gnome-keyring

When reading `gnome-keyring-daemon` manual, one can see pretty clearly that the `--components` option has four valid values: `ssh`, `secrets`, `gpg`, and `pkcs11`.

However, I couldn’t find any detailed explanation on these four options. Could someone detail the **use** and the **field of use** of each component of `gnome-keyring-daemon`?

(For instance it is obvious to me the `ssh` component is used to automatically decrypt ssh private-keys passphrases and feed them to `ssh` but other components (especially their field of use) remain obscure to me.)

Comment: I've never used g-k-d but here's what I know: they're briefly mentioned in the [source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-keyring/tree/HACKING). `secrets` is the [_secret storage service_](http://standards.freedesktop.org/secret-service/), `gpg` is the _GPG password agent_, ssh is the _SSH key agent_ and `pkcs#11` is the _Certificate and Key Storage_.

Comment: Thanks for those precisions, I’ll investigate the source when I have the time!

Answer (score 0):

The `--components` flag is only helpful to have finer control on which components will be started (or not). When you use it you are telling the keyring daemon to specifically use only those components and no others. There's an example in the [online manual for the Gnome Keyring](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Ssh):

> - If you're starting gnome-keyring manually or from a script you can use the --components option to exclude starting up the SSH support.
>
>   ```
>   $ gnome-keyring-daemon --components keyring,pkcs11
>   ```

Comment: Indeed that’s a precision I should have added to my original post. Now I’m seeking detailed documentation about all four options in order to only start those I actually need. (I see no point starting `secrets` if I don’t require the feature it provides…